Enhancing User Experience with Better Animation Button Design
Hi UX Stack Exchange Community,
I'm currently working on a mobile app design for the Mazda MX-5 modding community. The app allows users to execute animations with their car's lights (such as wink, sleep, open/close, with both lights or separately). While the core functionality is in place, I'm struggling with the design of the animation buttons. The idea is to have 3 to 6 predefined animation buttons and more can be added by the user itself
Here is what I have so far

Current Issue:
I like the icons I'm using, they're simple, clean, and intuitive (I think they are). However, the overall look of the buttons is lacking. They don't blend well with the rest of the UI, and the layout feels cluttered on smaller screens.
Here are some examples of my icons:

(> -) (left light winking, right one closed)
(- <) (right light winking, left one closed)
(> o) (left light winking, right one open)
A half circle on its side represents a sleepy eye.

Request for Help:
I would greatly appreciate any feedback, suggestions, or examples on how to improve the design of these animation buttons. Specifically:

Button Design: How can I improve the look of the buttons while keeping the icons?
Button Layout: Are there better ways to organize these buttons for better usability?
Visual Design: Any tips on enhancing the visual appeal?
Interaction Feedback: How should the buttons look and behave when clicked? What kind of visual or animation feedback should be provided to indicate the action has been executed?


Beyond the design, there are some elements at a perceptible level that could be improved.
A - The action will take place in both lights, not just one. The action area is horizontal (A) and each light is a square. By placing the action buttons in a square shape, it suggests that the action will only be performed on a single light by shape association (Gestalt principle of similarity), which leads to confusion. As these are elements with immediate visual response, I would try not to perceptually confuse the user.

B - The action to be performed is to turn on the lights in the illustration. Having the buttons lighter than the graphic makes it difficult to interpret the action to be carried out because the three buttons are already illuminated.
Based on what is described, I would try:

Changing the shape of the buttons by associating them with the shape of the action area
Making the buttons not overshadow the action they will perform in their passive state
Adding a hover or click effect illuminating the button at the moment of action


As for the design, you have many ideas searching for "car button dashboard".

Image source vectorstock
